# How to check via flask if a boolean in db sqlite is true

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, boolean

I'm writing a small site in flask with python. It's all new to me, but I've figures out how to create a site, routes, admin login, registration forms etc.

Now I want to check and remember that after a login you're an admin or not. I was thinking about solving this by a Boolean in my sqlite db. But I fail to check whether the Boolean is True or False.

It might be that this is not the best approach, if so, please point me in the right direction. And, nevertheless, it is an interesting thing for me to find out how to check a Boolean in my db.

For the db I have;

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

In the db this translates to;

```
sqlite> select * from user;
1|admin|test@test.com|sha256$c2GxyyGc$d4df5929026fa62e49a587a8275ed4c
0abfb45e6d35d3617146e7326c13367e1|1
2|user|user@test.com|sha256$9y9Pz2PY$d2445b365d98a55e041d32c9781fba22f4a9e7db72c
f4c490e3ac1b3d3a3ffd4|0
sqlite>
```

Where the last value is the "admin value"

To check the login, and whether you're an admin or not

```py
@app.route('/login', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
           user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
           if user:
               if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                   login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                   adm = User.query.filter(User.admin.is_(True)).first()
                   if adm == True:
                       return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
                   return redirect(url_for('index'))
           return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
    return render_template('login.html', form = form)
```

I expected to go to the dashboard, but instead I'm redirected to the index page.
If I return the value of adm I got this error:

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a User.

I understand this is clearly a strong hint but I can't get it right.

Comment: if you do `print(adm)`, what does it show ? To be more precise : When you do `print(adm)`, what does it print when you submit a correct input, and an incorrect one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement 
`user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()` 
should already return a `User` record, 
thus 
further query `adm = User.query.filter(User.admin.is_(True)).first()` makes no sense.
Check the needed attribute on extracted `User` record as shown below:

```
...
if form.validate_on_submit():
       user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
       if user:
           if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
               login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
               if user.admin:
                   return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
               return redirect(url_for('index'))
       return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
return render_template('login.html', form = form)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer to your problem, but it might be that the value of adm is 'None' and so Flask will simply throw an error as it does not consider it to be a valid return type. If that is the case you can try and set the value of adm to something that is not 'None' and see if the problem persists.